# Style status bar when navigation bar is hidden

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I know that with `UIKit` usually you just override:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle { return .lightContent }
```

in your `UIViewController` (or `UINavigationController` if it exists). **It works perfectly fine.**

---

However, I run into a problem when I perform this:

```
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
```

Now, I can see no navigation bar, which is expected and perfectly fine. However, I see the status bar with the dark font, what is unexpected (my navigation controller overrides above property and it works properly when the navigation bar is not hidden). I want to see the status bar, but I want it in a light font. Navigation controller from this point does not listen to `preferredStatusBarStyle`, so I can't set it up this way.

Is there any way to display `.lightContent` status bar style when the navigation bar is hidden..?

The end effect is visible on the screenshot. If you zoom in, you can see dark letters & battery on dark background.
[image: Screenshot of dark statusbar on dark background]

*PS. Please do not post answers only about SwiftUI (here we support old iOS as well) & deprecated stuff.*

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution to make SDK ask for style when there is a navigation controller and the navigation bar is hidden but the status bar is shown.

In `UINavigationController` subclass, you need to override

```
override var childForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? { return viewControllers.last }
```

And then inside these controllers, you can specify

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle { return .lightContent }
```

For some reason, if the navigation bar is hidden, iOS SDK does not ask navigation controller for `preferredStatusBarStyle`. However, it still asks `childForStatusBarStyle` and we've got an issue fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your status bar style to light
[image]

After that set View controller-based status bar appearance to NO in your info.plist

[image]

**UPDATE**

If you want the light content only in one view you can try to override the user interface style to dark in viewDidLoad

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    self.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, but did you actually read my question? I stated there that it is working perfectly fine when navigation bar is not hidden, so there's no point in doing such drastic things. Why drastic? Because your answer affects all screens, and I need to apply it only to one screen and only if there's dark mode selected.

Comment: It works for iOS 13+, and as I stated in the question, I support multiple iOS versions, so it's not suitable. I pasted a working solution as my answer below, please check it out :) Have a nice day!